# jQuery - variable inside img src returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay so I have an AJAX call that looks like this (left out non important code):

```
 function updateChat(){

    var userAvatar = $('.user-avatar').val();

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "index.php",
       data:{
           "AJAX": 'support-chat-process'
       },
       dataType: "JSON",
       success: function(data){

           var append ='somehtml';
           alert(userAvatar); // works!
           append += '<img src="' + userAvatar + '" height="30" width="30">'; 
           append += '<p>'+userAvatar+'</p>'; // also works!

           $('body').append(append);

       }
    });
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get a value from a hidden input field inside a variable that will add a HTML IMG tag to the document.

The value I get from that field (that I put into userAvatar) is correct. Alerting the variable both before and after the trouble-code also outputs the correct string.

If I put the variable inside `<p>` tags it will also work.

However when I add the variable to IMG src like above I get 'undefined' inside the src when it is added to the document.

So then in my html it looks like this:

```
      <img src="undefined" height="30" width="30">
```

I have no idea why, any ideas? I have not touched the variable besides the code im showing here.

Comment: is userAvatar a valid image url?

Comment: can you add a `alert(append)` before `$('body').append(append);`

Comment: Bernhard: yes its a valid image url, I can access it by copy-ing and pasting the output in <p>

Arun: done that, returns the exact same thing

Comment: What is the exact value of the userAvatar variable? And does manually adding the `<img/>` tag using the variable for the `src` work OK? This works OK for me: http://jsfiddle.net/sJ5WV/

Comment: please post the actual variable output

Comment: The code  <img src="undefined" height="30" width="30"> may be an initialization generated before AJAX call?

Comment: http://www.tourdog.nl/app/lib/i/test2.png is what userAvatar holds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have figured out the cause. I had an if/else statement inside the code and due to a typo it called the wrong variable. I learned that next time I better not leave out code I don't deem necessary in a question.